# React Native Screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-screens

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
> > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 20

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
error Failed to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

In your project's root terminal, run this below command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The main to my error was jdk version. Before i was using latest jdk 20 version which is not supported yet. So I had to downgrade my jdk version from 20 to 11 and then successfully build the app.

Comment: I think 17 also works

Comment: @Mister_CK 17 didn't work in my case. Only 11 worked.